# Why was a flag marked as disputed?

Tags: support, disputed-flags

I have flagged recently [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342324/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream) as a duplicate. But the flag was marked as disputed.

[image]

But, the post was marked as *duplicate* in the end.
So, why is my flag disputed?

Comment: Probably because of the outcome of triage https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26393395

Comment: This looks very confused.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, depends on the review queue, from which a flag was reported, the flag can be helpful or disputed.

Comment: I think it can also be declined, if it's a flag to close and the close vote queue decides to leave the post open (which is not the same as it not being handled, where the post is invalidated in the close vote queue). While from triage, the flag is disputed.